# Codeigniter/PHP: Creating users in batch with TankAuth

Tags: php, codeigniter, batch-file, tankauth

I am interested in creating bulk users/passwords in a batch using TankAuth for CodeIgniter. I asked this question on the CI forums but got no responses:

> http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/110993/P330/#837327

Google searches don't turn up much besides my thread as the third result and a bunch of unrelated sites.

> http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=create+batch+users+tankauth

Has anyone successfully done this using a recursion algorithm? If so, can you post some code to get me going on the right path? Thanks!

Versions of software:

CI 1.7.3

TankAuth 1.0.7

PHP 5.x

**EDIT 2/15:**

Just in case anyone is looking for a solution to this, here's a function that is basically the same one I used (there were some other parameters, but this should get you going):

```
function batchReg()
{
    $this->load->model('mymodel');

    // connect to the database
    $this->mymodel->dbconnect();

    // build it
    $query = "SELECT user, email, pass from newusers ORDER BY user ASC";

    // ship it
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // loop it
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data = $this->tank_auth->create_user($row['user'], $row['email'], $row['pass'], FALSE);
        print_r($data);
        echo "<p>";
    }

}
```

Just ping batchReg() from the controller to put it into action!

Comment: random usernames and random passwords?  or do you have a list somewhere?

Comment: I have a list. Ilya (the creator of TankAuth) responded with this:

"A new user is being registered by calling 'create_user' method of the library (controller auth.php, line 149). To create login for a bunch of users you have to retrieve them one by one from database and call this method for everyone of them. This method has following parameters: user login, email, password and email activation flag (has email to be confirmed by clicking a special link or not)."

I'm going to try and write a script here in the next few days; I'll update this ticket if I successfully do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a simple loop operation to me

somehow (whatever the source) get your usernames in a iterable form like an array `$user_list`

we'll say it looks like this

```
Array(
    Array(
        [username] => '...',
        [email]    => '...',
        [password] => '',     //leave password empty
    ),
    Array(
        [username] => '...',
        [email]    => '...',
        [password] => '',     //leave password empty
    ),
    ... etc.
)
```

Then create a simple looping routine to process the new registrations, storing the password back into the array, so you will then have a complete list of logins, new (randomized) passwords and emails.

```
//loop by referance in order to properly store the generated password
foreach($user_list as &$user) {

    //generate 8 char password and store it
    $user['password'] = substr(uniqid(),2,8);

    //run register routine (not sure on tank auth's specific syntax
    $this->tankauth->register($user['username'],$user['email'],$user['password'],FALSE);
}
```

Then at the end your `$user_list` contains all the new passwords for your users.

Comment: That's pretty much what I planned to do. You beat me to it! :) Guess I don't have to post my source now ;)